# Custom modification of the "new folder" command in windows 7

Tags: subdirectory

A while ago todofixthis, answering somebody else's question, provided a nice little .cmd file, which he called open_dos_here.cmd.   If you put this file in an arbitrary folder,then clicking on it would open a command window in that folder, rather than in the default folder.  I'd like to extend this facility to avoid having to copy and paste the .cmd file into the new folder every time I create one.     The easiest way to do this would be if I could customize windows' new folder command so that it does the copy and paste automatically whenever a new folder is created.   Is this possible?  If not, is there another way of accomplishing the same thing?

Thanks very much for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news for you. This functionality comes built-in with `Windows 7`.

Just press `SHIFT` before you *right-click* on a folder and select `Open command window here`.

[image: Open CMD here]

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the Windows context menu to add a shortcut to open a command prompt when right-clicking on a folder.

To add the option:

1. Run regedit.exe
2. Browse to
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Classes/Folder/Shell`.
3. Create a new key
   called "Command Prompt". For the default value, enter whatever text
   you want to appear when you right-click on a folder. eg.
   Open Command Prompt.
4. Create a new subkey called "Command". Set the
   default value to `Cmd.exe /k pushd %L`.
5. Exit the Registry Editor and your new right-click command will be ready to go.

Not exactly what you are asking for, but I use this on both my home and work PCs. It works a charm and sounds a lot easier than double-clicking a file every time.

Comment: This looks great!     Thanks very much indeed.   Will try it out